# Разница между optInt() и getInt() в JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

В чем разница между optInt() и getInt(), и почему getInt() не может (в моем случае) найти значение по ключу?

```
public String brand;
public String model;
public int price;
private static JSONArray head;
//Загружаю JSON из папки assets
public static void loadJSON() {
    try {
        InputStream is = GameActivity.assets.open("head.json");
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null) sb.append(line);
        head=new JSONObject(sb.toString()).getJSONArray("head");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//Получаю значения
public Clothes(int index) {
        JSONObject obj;
        try {
            obj = head.getJSONObject(index);
            this.brand=obj.optString("name"); //getString возвращает null
            this.model=obj.optString("model");
            this.price=obj.optInt("price"); //getInt не может найти значение по ключу
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ну и затем через new Clothes(index) получаю доступ ко всем интересующим полям.
Сам JSON http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=9259144d4ca974194d0e163fb5e26c6d

Answer (score 2):

Разница в том, что `optInt` возврашает 0 если поле не существует. Где [`getInt`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt(java.lang.String)) возврашает  [`JSONException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException.html) если указанное полу нету в Json объекте.

Если вам нужно что бы полу существовало, вы должны использовать `getInt`

Если полу опционально, и не важно что оно есть. тогда используйте [`optInt`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optInt(java.lang.String))

Если вам нужно указать значение, если нету поле, используйте [`optInt(<поле>,<значение по умолчанию>)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optInt(java.lang.String,%20int))

[документ](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)